# Unreachable target in open areas

Tags: nodes, anylogic, target, agent, levels

I'm working with the pedestrian library to create an agent-based simulation. When I run the model, I randomly get the bellow error for some simulation runs or random agents. But my nodes are free for columns and walls because are just open areas as parks and beaches.

How Can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Exception during discrete event execution
root.pedGoTo2.pedGoToTarget:
Unreachable target: (149.19, 500.00) on level 'name: level' for pedestrian 'id: 5' located at: (553.28, 229.48) on level 'name: level'!

Comment: Do share some screenshots of the actual layout. Sometimes, it looks fine but you create some problem areas that the algorithm struggles with

Answer (score 0):

when you work with pedestrians, and send them to a node, they go to a random point inside that node... and they don't care whether there's an obstacle there or not.

To avoid this issue...
Option 1: do not put walls (in particular closed walls) inside a node or inside an area that will be a destination for that pedestrian

Option 2: use polygonal nodes so the node goes around your closed walls.. Whichi is the same as option 1 really